# Problema de encryptacion en Laravel

Tags: laravel

Quiero hacer una nueva vista en mi aplicación de laravel, para que el usuario logueado pueda editar su perfil, mi problema viene cuando me da el error de:

```php
DecryptException in compiled.php line 13235:
The payload is invalid.
```

He debuggeado el metodo para ver que me devuelve la request cuando llama a la ruta para invocar la nueva vista y tiene el siguiente output:

> .Crypt::encrypt(Auth::user()->id)

Este el es método:

```php
public function show($id){
    dd($id);
    try {
        $decrypted_id = \Crypt::decrypt($id);
    } catch (DecryptException $e) {
        return redirect('/home');
    }
    $worker = Worker::find($decrypted_id);
    return view('worker.show')->with('worker',$worker);
}
```

la ruta:

```php
Route::get('/worker/show/{id_worker}', 'WorkerController@show');
```

y el pedazo de código de la vista principal que lleva al menu de editar perfil:

```php
 <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
     <a href="{{ url('/worker/show/.Crypt::encrypt(Auth::user()->id)') }}"
      class="dropdown-item">
         <i class="icon-head"></i> Editar Perfil
     </a>
 </div>
```

**¿Qué clase de problema existe?**

Saludos y gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me parece que el problema se está originando por la concatenación del valor.

Revisa la siguiente línea:

```
...
 <a href="{{ url('/worker/show/.Crypt::encrypt(Auth::user()->id)') }}" ... >
...
```

Cambiala por esta otra:

```
...
 <a href="{{ url('/worker/show/' . Crypt::encrypt(Auth::user()->id)) }}" ... >
...
```

Comment: Dios, que estupidez! muchísimas gracias, y siento las molestias.

Comment: Descuida, todos cometemos errores @DavidPazóLópez y los seguiremos cometiendo ten por seguro xD. Hiciste bien en debuggear, solo te faltó ubicar la línea del error ;)